# Use perl to find the font properties of MS-Word document

Tags: perl

What i need to do is... Read a word file and based on the properties of the font add a tag ahead of them to differentiate it as a header or a paragraph
However, i need to do this using Perl..
Is it possible???
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need more info to help you identify words you need to process. In my example I just searching for the text **Some** ([this is my *.docx file](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/47707959/fonts.docx))

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;
use Win32::OLE;

use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Variant;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Word';
$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;

print "Starting Word\n";

    my $Word = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Word.Application') ||
           Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application');
    $Word->{'Visible'}     = 1;
    $Word->{DisplayAlerts} = 0;

my $File = $Word->Documents->Open( "./fonts.docx" ) or die Win32::OLE->LastError;

$Word->Selection->HomeKey(wdStory);

$Word->Selection->Find->{'Text'} = 'Some';

$Word->Selection->Find->Execute();

say "Font size: [", $Word->Selection->Font->Size(), "]";
say "Font name: [", $Word->Selection->Font->Name(), "]";

$Word->Quit;
```

Answer (score 4):

@Nikita, This shall give you the detailed view of how its done :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Word';
#$Win32::OLE::CP = CP_UTF8;
binmode STDOUT, 'encoding(utf8)';

# OPEN FILE SPECIFIED AS FIRST ARGUMENT
my $fname=$ARGV[0]; 
my $fnameFullPath = `cygpath.exe -wa $fname`;
$fnameFullPath =~ s/\\/\\\\/g;
$fnameFullPath =~ s/\s*$//;
unless (-e $fnameFullPath) { print "Error: File did not exists\n"; exit 1;}

# STARTING OLE
my $Word = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Word.Application')
    || Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application','Quit')
    or die Win32::OLE->LastError();

$Word->{'Visible'} = 0;
my $doc = $Word->Documents->Open($fnameFullPath);
my $paragraphs = $doc->Paragraphs() ;
my $enumerate = new Win32::OLE::Enum($paragraphs);

# PROCESSING PARAGRAPHS
while(defined(my $paragraph = $enumerate->Next())) {

    my $text = $paragraph->{Range}->{Text};
    my $sel = $Word->Selection;
    my $font = $sel->Font;

    if ($font->{Size} == 18){
        print "Text: ", $text, "\n";
        print "Font Bold: ", $font->{Bold}, "\n";
        print "Font Italic: ", $font->{Italic}, "\n";
        print "Font Name: ", $font->{Name}, "\n";
        print "Font Size: ", $font->{Size}, "\n";
        print "=========\n";
    }
}

# CLOSING OLE
$Word->ActiveDocument->Close ;
$Word->Quit;
```

The output will be such:

```
Text: This is a doc file containing different fonts and size, document also contain header and footer (Font: TNR, Size: 18)
Font Bold: 0
Font Italic: 0
Font Name: Times New Roman
Font Size: 18
=========
Text: This is a Perl example (Font TNR, Size: 12)
Font Bold: 0
Font Italic: 0
Font Name: Times New Roman
Font Size: 18
=========
Text: This is a Python example(Font: Courier New, Size: 10)
Font Bold: 0
Font Italic: 0
Font Name: Times New Roman
Font Size: 18
=========
```

Comment: I have worked with this code but cudnt find properties for all the paragraphs. Neways thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use OLE automatization, the [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aOLE) module is helpful.
This way requires deeper knowledge on Word OLE api.